# MVC3 vCard download fails on mobile devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to write an MVC3 application that dynamically builds a vCard(.vcf) file to be downloaded by folks on a mobile device when they scan a QR code. I found an example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/22/creating-vcard-action-result.aspx) to build and return vCards. After some manipulation I was able to get it working on my desktop machine, but every time I try to download the file on a mobile device the download fails. I had thought it was something wrong with the headers it was sending, so I did some digging and found some useful information on HTTP headers for android [here](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/). Unfortunate even tweaking the headers did not change anything.

The first part is the controller, later this will be taking URL parameters. Keeping it simple for testing.

```
public class APIController : Controller
{

public vCardResult vCard()
{
    vCard card = new vCard
    {
        FirstName = "First",
        LastName = "Last",
        StreetAddress = "70 Street Adr.",
        City = "Atlanta",
        State = "GA",
        CountryName = "United States",
        Mobile = "5558675309",
        Organization = "MyCompany",
        HomePage = "www.Google.com",
        JobTitle = "Software Developer",
        Zip = "30318",
        Email = "FirstLast@MyCompany.com",
    };

    return new vCardResult(card);
}
```

And here is the vCard Model

```
public class vCard
{
    //I cut out the properties to save space

    public override string ToString()
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
        builder.AppendLine("VERSION:2.1");
        builder.AppendLine("FN:" + FirstName + " " + LastName);
        builder.AppendLine("N:" + LastName + ";" + FirstName);
        builder.AppendLine("TEL;CELL:" + Mobile);
        builder.AppendLine("TEL:");
        builder.AppendLine("EMAIL;INTERNET:" + Email);
        builder.AppendLine("TEL;FAX:");
        builder.AppendLine("TITLE:" + JobTitle);
        builder.AppendLine("ORG:" + Organization);
        builder.AppendLine("ADR:;;" + StreetAddress + ";" + City + ";" + ";" + Zip + ";");
        builder.AppendLine("REV:20120730T15034z");
        builder.AppendLine("END:VCARD");

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
```

And lastly the action result

```
public class vCardResult : ActionResult
{
    private vCard _card;

    protected vCardResult() { }

    public vCardResult(vCard card)
    {
        _card = card;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)

    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/vcard";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + _card.FirstName + "_" + _card.LastName + ".VCF\"");

        var cardString = _card.ToString();
        var inputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        var outputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1257");
        var cardBytes = inputEncoding.GetBytes(cardString);

        var outputBytes = Encoding.Convert(inputEncoding,
                                outputEncoding, cardBytes);

        response.OutputStream.Write(outputBytes, 0, outputBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Not too much different from the example I listed earlier but I wanted to get at least this functioning before I went too much further.

I examined the response sent from the server with the response of a similar working system (one that I have no access to source code) and I don't see many differences so I'm not sure why their vCard opens the phone's contact list to add as a new contact and my download fails. The responses are as follows.

**Example Response (working):**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=5240000053568089.vcf
Content-Type: text/x-vcard
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 21:18:31 GMT

110
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:First Last
N:Last;First
TEL;CELL:5558675309
TEL:
EMAIL;INTERNET:FirstLast@MyCompany.com
TEL;FAX:
TITLE:Software Developer
ORG:MyCompany
ADR:;;70 Street Adr.;Atlanta;GA;30318;
REV:20120523T150346Z
END:VCARD

0
```

**The response from *my* application**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/vcard
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; fileName=First_Last.vcf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 20:14:02 GMT

105
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:First Last
N:Last;First
TEL;CELL:5558675309
TEL:
EMAIL;INTERNET:FirstLast@MyCompany.com
TEL;FAX:
TITLE:Software Developer
ORG:MyCompany
ADR:;;70 Street Adr.;Atlanta;GA;30346;
REV:20120730T15034z
END:VCARD

0
```

Thanks in advance for reading this and for any help/advice you are able to offer!

Answer (score 0):

You never closed your:

```
public class APIController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

- First thing need to change content type to : text/x-vcard
- Then I've found that only ASP MVC FileContentResult work. So for
  appropriate way to get contact by asp instead of rewriting HTTP
  headers just use line above: File(outputBytes, "text/x-vcard",
  Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
- Third don't know is it 100% right but you action have to take GET
  request and conatains ".vcf" extension like:
  somesite.com/ControllerName/ActionName.vcf

But standart setup of web config disallow dots so

- Forth add some inchancments to you config

  <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
    <add path="*.vcf" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" />
  </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
    <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*.vcf" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

This some tricky way to download vcard by android browser but it express more complex to solve download contacts by other phone browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
using Maavak.Models;
using Maavak.Models.Vcard;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace Maavak.Controllers
{
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VCardTestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public VCardTestController(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        )
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _vcard = new Vcard
        {
            FirstName = "First",
            LastName = "Last",
            StreetAddress = "70 Street Adr.",
            City = "Atlanta",
            State = "GA",
            CountryName = "United States",
            Mobile = "5558675309",
            Organization = "MyCompany",
            HomePage = "www.Google.com",
            JobTitle = "Software Developer",
            Zip = "30318",
            Email = "FirstLast@MyCompany.com",
        };
    }

    private readonly Vcard _vcard;

    [Route("vcardtest.vcf")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            const string text_x_vcard = "text/x-vcard";
            HttpResponse response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/vcard";
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + _vcard.FirstName + "_" + _vcard.LastName + ".VCF\"");

            string cardString = _vcard.ToString();
            Encoding inputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            Encoding outputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
            byte[] cardBytes = inputEncoding.GetBytes(cardString);

            byte[] outputBytes = Encoding.Convert(inputEncoding,
                                    outputEncoding, cardBytes);

            return Content(cardString, text_x_vcard, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{ ClsGlobal.GetCurrentMethod() }] { ex.Message } : { ex.InnerException } - {ex.StackTrace}");
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this is the class

```
using System.Text;

namespace Maavak.Models.Vcard
{
public class Vcard
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string LandLine { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string HomePage { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
        builder.AppendLine("VERSION:2.1");
        builder.AppendLine($"N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{ LastName };{ FirstName};;;;");
        builder.AppendLine($"FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{ FirstName } { LastName }");
        //builder.AppendLine("FN:" + FirstName + " " + LastName);
        //builder.AppendLine("N:" + LastName + ";" + FirstName);
        if (Mobile != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;CELL:" + Mobile);
        if (LandLine != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;MOME:" + LandLine);
        if (Email != null)
            builder.AppendLine("EMAIL;INTERNET:" + Email);
        if (Fax != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;FAX:");
        if (JobTitle != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TITLE:" + JobTitle);
        if (Organization != null)
            builder.AppendLine("ORG:" + Organization);
        if (City != null)
            builder.AppendLine("ADR:;;" + StreetAddress + ";" + City + ";" + ";" + Zip + ";");
        //builder.AppendLine("REV:20120730T15034z");
        builder.AppendLine("END:VCARD");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

working demo  [here](https://maavak.taboil.com/vcardtest.vcf)!

Answer (score 0):

```
using Maavak.Models;
using Maavak.Models.Vcard;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace Maavak.Controllers
{
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VCardController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public VCardController(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        )
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    [Route("{FirstName}-{LastName}-{Mobile}-{LandLine}-{Email}.vcf")]
    public IActionResult Get(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string mobile,
        string landLine,
        string email
        )
    {
        try
        {
            Vcard _vcard = new Vcard()
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                Mobile = mobile,
                LandLine = landLine,
                Email = email
            };
            const string text_x_vcard = "text/x-vcard";
            HttpResponse response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/vcard";
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + _vcard.FirstName + " " + _vcard.LastName + ".VCF\"");

            return Content(_vcard.ToString(), text_x_vcard, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{ ClsGlobal.GetCurrentMethod() }] { ex.Message } : { ex.InnerException } - {ex.StackTrace}");
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And then use it like

https://maavak.taboil.com/first-last-55555-66666-first@last.com.vcf

Answer (score 0):

this solution is for hebrew characters

```
using Maavak.Models;
using Maavak.Models.Vcard;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Maavak.Controllers
{
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VCardController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public VCardController(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        )
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    [Route("{FirstName}-{LastName}-{Mobile}-{LandLine}-{Email}.vcf")]
    public IActionResult Get(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string mobile,
        string landLine,
        string email
        )
    {
        const string text_x_vcard = "text/x-vcard";
        try
        {
            Vcard _vcard = new Vcard()
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                Mobile = mobile,
                LandLine = landLine,
                Email = email
            };

            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" +
                CleanNonAsciiForVcardHeadr(_vcard.FirstName) + " " +
                CleanNonAsciiForVcardHeadr(_vcard.LastName) + ".VCF\"");

            return Content(_vcard.ToString(), text_x_vcard, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{ ClsGlobal.GetCurrentMethod() }] { ex.Message } : { ex.InnerException } - {ex.StackTrace}");
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    private string CleanNonAsciiForVcardHeadr(string str)
    {
        return WebUtility.UrlEncode(str).Replace("+", "%20");
    }
}
}
```

and the class is this

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Maavak.Models.Vcard
{
public class Vcard
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string LandLine { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string HomePage { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        string n = $"{ CleanNonAsciiForVcard(LastName) };{ CleanNonAsciiForVcard(FirstName) };;;";
        string fn = $"{ CleanNonAsciiForVcard(FirstName) } { CleanNonAsciiForVcard(LastName) }";
        builder.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
        builder.AppendLine("VERSION:2.1");
        builder.AppendLine($"N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{ n }");
        builder.AppendLine($"FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{ fn }");
        //builder.AppendLine("FN:" + FirstName + " " + LastName);
        //builder.AppendLine("N:" + LastName + ";" + FirstName);
        if (Mobile != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;CELL:" + Mobile);
        if (LandLine != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;HOME:" + LandLine);
        if (Email != null)
            builder.AppendLine("EMAIL;INTERNET:" + Email);
        if (Fax != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TEL;FAX:");
        if (JobTitle != null)
            builder.AppendLine("TITLE:" + JobTitle);
        if (Organization != null)
            builder.AppendLine("ORG:" + Organization);
        if (City != null)
            builder.AppendLine("ADR:;;" + StreetAddress + ";" + City + ";" + ";" + Zip + ";");
        //builder.AppendLine("REV:20120730T15034z");
        builder.AppendLine("END:VCARD");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    private string CleanNonAsciiForVcard(string str)
    {
        return WebUtility.UrlEncode(str).Replace("+", "=20").Replace("%", "=");
    }
}
}
```

use it like this

https://maavak.taboil.com/first-last-55555-66666-first@last.com.vcf

or

https://maavak.taboil.com/first-last-55555-%20-%20.vcf

[https://maavak.taboil.com/עברית-עברית%20משפחה-55555-%20-%20.vcf](https://maavak.taboil.com/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%94-55555-%20-%20.vcf)